# How to run Puppeteer on a Docker container on a MacOS Apple Silicon M1 arm64 host

Tags: node.js, docker, jestjs, puppeteer

I'm unable to run my unit tests on Puppeteer inside of a Docker container. My host is a MacOS with Apple Silicon M1 (arm64) chip. I've also tried to follow the instructions from [the Puppeteer Github documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker) but they are meant for amd64 instead. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Installing puppeteer NPM package directly won't work for some reason and sadly the official Puppeteer documentation in GitHub is not compatible with arm64 architecture.

This is how I've prepared my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y chromium \
    fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
    --no-install-recommends
    
USER node # non-root user that comes with `node` images.

WORKDIR /app

COPY --chown=node package.json .
COPY --chown=node package-lock.json .

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/bin/chromium

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node . /app
```

The Dockerfile as it is configured is native to Apple Silicon (linux/arm64) as well as native for amd64 (linux/amd64) architectures.

You also must pass `--no-sandbox` argument to the browser on your code:

```js
export async function createBrowserInstance(): Promise<puppeteer.Browser> {
    return await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox'], // Required.
        headless: true,
    });
}
```

The extra flag disables the browser's dev sandboxing, so make sure to access only trusted pages. Otherwise it's fine. Please, somebody from the future, please feel free to edit this answer or comment how to get rid of the `--no-sandbox` argument.

Comment: Your Dockerfile is 10x neater than the official Puppeteer one. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work on Graviton2 (AWS ARM CPUs)

Comment: Web crawling. It’s because they are ARM machines. It’s Puppeteer’s fault since it doesn’t have first class container support. I do run Puppet workloads on ARM architecture in production, just without Docker.

Comment: I couldn’t get Puppet to run on ARM in Docker.

Comment: "It’s Puppeteer’s fault since it doesn’t have first class container support" - not true anymore - https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#running-in-docker

Comment: This worked for me, check it out https://github.com/juananpe/puppeteer-in-docker-in-m1

Answer (score 6):

The only way I have been able to run `Puppeteer` via `Docker` on `Apple Silicon` is by.

1. Creating the image by specifying `amd64` platform

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:18
```

2. Enabling "Use Rosetta" support in Docker Desktop

[image]

3. Following the current `Puppeteer` `Docker` instructions to manually install `Chromium` instead of installing it as part of Puppeteer.

### Modified Puppeteer Docker File

This example simplifies the current Puppeteer instructions.  I removed their create user instructions because one is included in the `node` image.  Also, they wipe out the `apt registry` after installing Chromium, preventing you from installing anything else.  Add that back if you feel the need.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:18

# We can define environment variables here
# instead of specifying them when we launch Puppeteer. 
# The path may change depending on your platform and installed binary.
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/googlechrome-linux-keyring.gpg \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/googlechrome-linux-keyring.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-khmeros fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends

# If you desire to run in Chrome sandbox mode, change to a non-root user, and make sure you launch your image with `cap_add: SYS_ADMIN`.

USER node
```

## Running As Non-Root With Chromium Sandbox Enabled

1. Set a non-root user in your `dockerfile`
2. Enable cap_add: SYS_ADMIN when launching your image.

Example `docker compose`

```
services: {
  node: {
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
  }
}
```

With the environment variables set in `DOCKERFILE`, cap_add set, and a non-root user running, you can just fire up Puppeteer with it's default paranoid sandboxing.

In DOCKERFILE

```
# Use the non-root user that comes with `node` image,
# Or another if you wish.
USER node
```

In your Javascript

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   headless: true
})
```

## Running As Root And Bypassing Chromium Sandbox

If you would rather rough it and disable Chromium Sandbox, just run as the default `root` user, and turn off the sandbox protection.

1. Do not set a user in your `dockerfile`
2. When launching Puppeteer, disable the sandbox

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   args: [
     '--no-sandbox'
   ],
   headless: true
})
```

References:

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I am debugging a fonts issue with puppeteer and need to setup a linux container locally on an M1 Mac. I will note for anyone else that comes by this thread, is that I couldn't build my image if Rosetta is enabled first. It hangs on libc-bin file when installing Chrome. Enabled it after the build (in the middle of building it now and I am passed the placed it kept locking up).

Answer (score 0):

If you share your codebase with not ARM members, you could use **if ARM then** in your Dockerfile to be compatible with your colleagues.

```
# ... common dockerfile commands shared for all architectures

# Chromium fix for ARM (like Apple M1) 
RUN if [ "$(uname -m)" = "aarch64" ] ; then \
        apt-get update && apt-get install -y chromium ; \
        export PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true ; \
        export PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser ; \
    fi
```