# Running x86-compiled chromium on M2 chip docker fails

Tags: docker, chromium, apple-m1, apple-silicon, rosetta

I have compiled [Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#Run-Chromium) from source on an `x86_64 LINUX/UNIX` platform, which I'm trying to run within Docker form my apple-silicon MacOS using the *Rosetta* feature as suggested in other [community posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71452265/how-to-run-puppeteer-on-a-docker-container-on-a-macos-apple-silicon-m1-arm64-hos).

When Chromium runs, it seems it acknowledges the support for Rosetta but for some reason it exists with the following error:

```
root@66a8ce3454db:/# /usr/src/app/dist/chrome --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer --enable-logging --v=1 --no-sandbox
[0607/172836.307804:WARNING:stack_trace_posix.cc(857)] Failed to open file: /rosetta/rosetta
  Error: Success
[0607/172836.445340:WARNING:stack_trace_posix.cc(857)] Failed to open file: /rosetta/rosetta
  Error: Success
[0607/172836.445575:WARNING:stack_trace_posix.cc(857)] Failed to open file: /rosetta/rosetta
  Error: Success
[769:769:0607/172837.065567:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(162)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
[0607/172837.119752:WARNING:stack_trace_posix.cc(857)] Failed to open file: /rosetta/rosetta
  Error: Success
[769:769:0607/172837.901890:ERROR:power_monitor_device_source_linux.cc(70)] Failed to connect to org.freedesktop.login1.Manager for signal PrepareForSleep
[769:769:0607/172837.908870:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(590)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: unknown error type: 
[769:793:0607/172839.734885:FATAL:process_linux.cc(231)] Check failed: result == 0. : Permission denied (13)
#0 0x55555f6afd22 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x55555f696913 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x55555f588a1d logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#3 0x55555f589858 logging::ErrnoLogMessage::~ErrnoLogMessage()
#4 0x55555f570070 logging::(anonymous namespace)::DCheckErrnoLogMessage::~DCheckErrnoLogMessage()
#5 0x55555f56fb77 logging::CheckError::~CheckError()
#6 0x55555f67eb9b base::Process::SetProcessBackgrounded()
#7 0x55555d688c23 content::internal::ChildProcessLauncherHelper::SetProcessBackgroundedOnLauncherThread()
#8 0x55555cd2bc92 base::internal::FunctorTraits<>::Invoke<>()
#9 0x55555f5f327e base::TaskAnnotator::RunTaskImpl()
#10 0x55555f63e3a1 base::internal::TaskTracker::RunBlockShutdown()
#11 0x55555f63dbd9 base::internal::TaskTracker::RunTask()
#12 0x55555f63d513 base::internal::TaskTracker::RunAndPopNextTask()
#13 0x55555f6542dd base::internal::WorkerThread::RunWorker()
#14 0x55555f653ecd base::internal::WorkerThread::RunDedicatedWorker()
#15 0x55555f653d52 base::internal::WorkerThread::ThreadMain()
#16 0x55555f67c418 base::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadFunc()
#17 0x7fffff17bb43 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x94b42)
#18 0x7fffff20cbb4 clone
Task trace:
#0 0x55555cd2b4b5 content::ChildProcessLauncher::SetProcessBackgrounded()
#1 0x5555605aad7d IPC::(anonymous namespace)::ChannelAssociatedGroupController::Accept()
#2 0x555560453367 mojo::SimpleWatcher::Context::Notify()
Crash keys:
  "total-discardable-memory-allocated" = "1490"
  "gpu-gl-renderer" = "Disabled"
  "gpu-gl-vendor" = "Disabled"
  "gpu-generation-intel" = "0"
  "gpu_count" = "0"
  "gpu-devid" = "0x0000"
  "gpu-venid" = "0x0000"
  "ui_scheduler_async_stack" = "0x555560452C9D 0x555560452C9D"
  "num-extensions" = "0"
  "breadcrumbs" = "0:00:02 Tab1 StartNav3 #renderer-script #auto_subframe
0:00:02 Tab1 PageLoad #ntp
0:00:01 Tab1 PageLoad
0:00:01 Tab1 FinishNav2
0:00:01 Tab1 StartNav2 #renderer-script #auto_subframe
0:00:01 Tab1 AddInfobar44
0:00:01 Tab1 FinishNav1
0:00:00 Tab1 AddInfobar45
0:00:00 Tab1 AddInfobar43
0:00:00 Browser1 Insert active Tab1 at 0
0:00:00 Tab1 StartNav1 #ntp #auto_toplevel
0:00:00 Startup
"
  "io_scheduler_async_stack" = "0x555560453367 0x0"
  "reentry_guard_tls_slot" = "unused"
  "variations" = "db59f83a-3f4a17df,8bccc03b-3f4a17df,5f2c0f7c-3f4a17df,da493d3c-3f4a17df,ecaca27c-a123a0cf,391562d6-3f4a17df,9f476f76-3f4a17df,f3ed486d-3f4a17df,5c783e42-8f8fa88f,e28cd73c-3f4a17df,36d5ee52-3f4a17df,b13ca3d9-84f6cff8,65570806-377be55a,8659ca17-3f4a17df,ade3efeb-e1cc0f14,3fd33f16-27b09c4c,3095b8fe-3f4a17df,3f9314a8-3f4a17df,1166396-1166396,5f36436a-f799c15e,fc9ceed7-3f4a17df,87a22c16-5123f057,5de2eeca-3f4a17df,baee3c29-3f4a17df,9fe21c85-3f4a17df,78aca32-3f4a17df,250dda8b-3f4a17df,5be458ba-78266b16,fd4b313c-3f4a17df,afa71e8b-aea4882e,e5ade537-e5ade537,47be28a0-3f4a17df,ef4764d7-c9f4d4ef,a779bb20-3f4a17df,f0682056-324bfab2,788db06c-edf91aba,2da2abac-b7f59038,d3566fbd-c6f74b94,75ffb03a-3f4a17df,3e6ca8ad-3f4a17df,c4e32a07-3a3251a9,741e95d4-3f4a17df,a83da733-3f4a17df,1b245f0d-eaf735a3,520b2a89-88bf9f37,42f1f10d-98837767,ad4acdda-3f4a17df,7fb629a1-60fdb59,90860314-3f4a17df,de2c80ca-da5d16c4,6ad21bf6-727a1257,ca12356a-ee1c2cee,28410024-3f4a17df,b1ceb06f-3f4a17df,d2e8e6e4-3f4a17df,8c82550d-3f4a17df,933702bb-3f4a17df,a2fd384c-cc71bb94,1fce7d57-3f4a17df,278baf51-3f4a17df,35a386c3-3f4a17df,90fa3bb1-3f4a17df,e8c68789-49a20295,b53f3ef9-3f4a17df,d990c4ac-3f4a17df,e0e63e5f-decb98bf,edddf950-49eb759f,911e33b9-3f4a17df,19d422be-c9846617,201e98ca-53757ab,5c7c8339-3f4a17df,e521d2ef-3f4a17df,e79d4056-80f9a33e,7ec047c2-3f4a17df,ec21b181-3f4a17df,4d936449-fd549ada,9e5c75f1-30e1b12b,83a09cba-fcf6c09,1acce950-3f4a17df,a18444ea-a18444ea,eddd0d82-3f4a17df,99c32967-f0a9a61e,4749874c-455e925b,824b2e8d-6b54c43,caa76e48-caa76e48,857feb0-3f4a17df,b0f15b33-b0f15b33,7760b5b2-3f4a17df,5c4d440e-58c8ac88,de95f00f-3f4a17df,f112d133-3f4a17df,78634d5f-2ba5dc1c,690e2db1-3f4a17df,cd59be9a-6e5c8f84,c80a7778-85a1d8e4,b16eab85-95ab9b79,e52d4c86-3f4a17df,13427e22-3f4a17df,4ff8f5b5-9c1f9d3b,5851a53a-8897814c,8d7344de-3f4a17df,910af27f-3f4a17df,50eaf59c-3f4a17df,f2855e3d-de2b6078,87f33ad6-3f4a17df,fd051c38-3f4a17df,3eabe0b8-3e066f82,17cd3426-3f4a17df,77b7ea96-9a159164,1bb6a450-3f4a17df,3e99ae8f-21e7ece7,b349dbf8-3f4a17df,5be633d-3f4a17df,870c1db8-3f4a17df,f14c322f-f9a43703,78ccea4c-3f4a17df,263848e4-3f4a17df,ae850472-3f4a17df,9982045c-3f4a17df,cf64b238-3f4a17df,a79ba57a-f23d1dea,ea23a088-41c37e8a,371f259c-3f4a17df,b46f46d-3f4a17df,f6e27768-f695fd79,3b96a1d-3f4a17df,ebf54a8-3f4a17df,6becb1e-a6ea97a2,76415c5-e21d85d9,595f5eb0-f23d1dea,f73d1d52-3f4a17df,44b22d82-3f4a17df,1584cf60-3f4a17df,bbaef9b4-3f4a17df,42f0e0ea-75d6947c,160d8d8d-9d12ca0c,4ea303a6-3f4a17df,3042ad4b-ad2fa222,b3c54bb3-a058b5d3,f654ad46-c94f66c2,81b1a2c3-3f4a17df,d92d97b4-e913bec6,94f1fa38-66264bee,d7d493f4-a9412e3f,565dffc5-565dffc5,9a564e2a-3f4a17df,d664a1aa-3f4a17df,31af02a2-3f4a17df,dda927e2-3f4a17df,19306e3-3f4a17df,3e7d7783-a4655118,18324944-3f4a17df,186d6e2c-36c0e608,26016f9f-4df4f25e,8a2f86d8-3f4a17df,b2cff759-3f4a17df,8ddeb5cd-3f4a17df,aa21b4f1-3f4a17df,15e85316-3f4a17df,3e8fe123-3f4a17df,48610cc8-3f4a17df,2f7e7ede-3f4a17df,b6377a55-53de90c2,dfa02032-7ae17237,ee9c60c1-20131bcc,9481ce98-3d47f4f4,4b935545-3d47f4f4,be338734-dee66fa8,70678518-dee66fa8,5f9907a9-dee66fa8,8eeccb9a-dee66fa8,2b465683-dee66fa8,9a38bae3-3d47f4f4,c9af35af-ec47f63d,2d1e43a3-3d47f4f4,b0455224-417b7a1e,d4e31d2-417b7a1e,d69d967d-3695c92e,"
  "num-experiments" = "178"
  "switch-3" = "--no-sandbox"
  "switch-2" = "--disable-software-rasterizer"
  "switch-1" = "--disable-gpu"
  "num-switches" = "7"
  "osarch" = "x86_64"
  "pid" = "769"
  "ptype" = "browser"

[0607/172839.910508:ERROR:elf_image_reader.cc(677)] no dynamic segment
[0607/172839.914295:WARNING:process_reader_linux.cc(144)] no stack mapping
[0607/172839.914658:WARNING:process_reader_linux.cc(144)] no stack mapping
[0607/172839.914842:WARNING:process_reader_linux.cc(144)] no stack mapping
[0607/172839.919244:WARNING:process_reader_linux.cc(144)] no stack mapping
[0607/172839.919448:WARNING:process_reader_linux.cc(144)] no stack mapping
[0607/172839.927050:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0607/172839.927414:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
assertion failed [arm::is_brk_instruction(instruction)]: SIGTRAP from kernel was not from a BRK
(ThreadContextRuntimeSignals.cpp:351 translate_sigtrap)
```

I'm curious into why it's attempting to open file `/rosetta/rosetta`. After some research I couldn't find anything around it being an Alpha feature

Comment: Looks like it's unable to find `Failed to open file: /rosetta/rosetta`

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? We are experiencing the same issue on M1 macs.

Comment: I think it had to do with using the wrong docker context. It works with `desktop-linux` which is basically Docker Desktop